# How to create an arc shaped progress bar in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a progress bar like the following image.

My requirements are:
1. I want to be able to set a progress value to it programmatically. 
2. I want to be able to change the colors of the arc - both the background one (grey) and the foreground one (green).

I looked into libraries but found none that do it in this particular shape and style. I am not proficient enough in creating custom drawables to be able to create this by myself. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the above answer, you can also use [CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) which seems to have something that looks exactly like your use case:

[image]

Usage:

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

Also, if you check the license on this library (bottom of their README), it seems like it's very favorable to using it however you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SeekArc](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc). It can do everything you need to get that result.

It would look something like this

```
<com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:arcColor="@color/grey"
    seekarc:progressColor="@color/green"
    seekarc:touchInside="true" />
```